# How to set different spacing between navigation menu items?

Tags: html, css, navigationbar

Here's a picture:

[image]

Addendum: I hope this this picture makes it more clear to what is asked...

I have a horizontal navigation menu with equal spacing between items... But I need different spacing between some of them. e.g. the spacing between "Arts / Illustrations" and "Contact" should be wider than between "Interior Design" and Arts / Illustrations. Any suggestions how can that be achieved?

https://codepen.io/abudimir/pen/bXVdxW

I tried playing with padding and margins but then all the items move. I've tried adding a separate class for that items but all the items move regardless.

```css
/* the whole menu */

#menu {
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}


/* Horizontal list menu */

.top-link {
  display: inline-block;
  float: none;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  font-weight: bolder;
}


/*Style for menu links*/

.top-link a {
  display: block;
  /* links fill the block*/
  color: var(--text-color);
  width: 100%;
  padding: 1.2em 2.7em;
  line-height: 1rem;
  text-align: center;
}


/*Hover state for top level links*/

.top-link:hover a {
  background: red;
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul id="menu">

    <li class="top-link">
      <a href="about.html">About</a>
    </li>

    <li class="top-link">
      <a href="#">Graphical Design</a>
    </li>

    <li class="top-link">
      <a href="#">Interior Design</a>
    </li>

    <li class="top-link">
      <a class="a3" href="#">Arts / Illustrations</a>
    </li>

    <li class="top-link">
      <a href="contact.html">Contact</a>
    </li>

  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
   ul li:last-child {
    margin-left: 50rem;
}
```

this should work.

```css
/* the whole menu */
 #menu {
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
} 

/* Horizontal list menu */
.top-link {
  display: inline-block;
  float: none;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  font-weight: bolder;
}

/*Style for menu links*/
.top-link a {
  display: block; /* links fill the block*/
  color: var(--text-color);
  width: 100%;
  padding: 1.2em 2.7em;
  line-height: 1rem;
  text-align: center;
}

/*Hover state for top level links*/
.top-link:hover a {
  background: red;
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}

ul li:last-child {
    margin-left: 50rem;
}
```

```html
<nav>
      <ul id="menu">

        <li class="top-link"> <a href="about.html">About</a> </li>

        <li class="top-link">
            <a href="#">Graphical Design</a>
        </li>

        <li class="top-link"> <a href="#">Interior Design</a>
        </li>

        <li class="top-link"> <a class="a3" href="#">Arts / Illustrations</a>
          </li>

        <li class="top-link"> <a href="contact.html">Contact</a> </li>

      </ul>
  </nav>
```

Comment: Kcsujeet, no, that's not the solution. It does make more space between the two items but also in the process moves all the other links too. I need all the other links that are on the left of the "Arts / Illustrations"  to stay where they are. With this margin, everything moves...

Comment: check my edited answer. let me know if this is what you want.

Comment: Can you please take a look at this picture? Maybe that will explain what's happening with all of your suggestions.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/7toUv.jpg

Comment: i did check out this picture before making changes to  my answer. its works exactly the way you want on  my side. is it not working good on your end?

Comment: Just tested it again. When changing the value of your margin-left, spacing increases / decreases between the wanted items but as a side effect, all other links move left or right. I don't understand how is it not possible to space 2 items without affecting the position of the others. All other margins/padding have been reset to 0.

Answer (score 0):

You can alternatively do the layout using CSS flex and apply `flex-grow: 2;` for those elements that needs to be wider. Please find the demo below

```css
/* the whole menu */

#menu {
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
}


/* Horizontal list menu */

.top-link {
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-basis: 0%;
  display: inline-block;
  flex-grow: 1;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  font-weight: bolder;
  padding: 1.2em 0;
}

.wider {
  flex-grow: 2;
}


/*Style for menu links*/

.top-link a {
  display: block;
  /* links fill the block*/
  color: var(--text-color);
  line-height: 1rem;
  text-align: center;
}


/*Hover state for top level links*/

.top-link:hover {
  background: red;
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul id="menu">

    <li class="top-link"> <a href="about.html">About</a> </li>

    <li class="top-link wider">
      <a href="#">Graphical Design</a>
    </li>

    <li class="top-link"> <a href="#">Interior Design</a>
    </li>

    <li class="top-link"> <a class="a3" href="#">Arts / Illustration</a>
    </li>

    <li class="top-link"> <a href="contact.html">Contact</a> </li>

  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Thanks, Joseph, but with flex I ran into problems when trying to make responsive menu using pure CSS only as you can see here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56936267/responsive-submenu-doesnt-show-on-small-screen
. 
That's why I reverted to inline-block solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```
 /* the whole menu */
 #menu {
  text-align: center;
  width: 80%;
  margin: auto;
 } 

/* Horizontal list menu */
.top-link {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  font-weight: bolder;
}

/*Style for menu links*/
.top-link a {
  display: block; /* links fill the block*/
  color: var(--text-color);
  width: 100%;
  padding: 1.2em 2.7em;
  line-height: 1rem;
  text-align: center;
}

/*Hover state for top level links*/
.top-link:hover a {
  background: red;
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}
#menu li:nth-child(4) {
  margin-right: 130px
}
```

Comment: You might want to explain how this helps and what the original problem is.

Comment: :D Amarat, I know how to set spacing between links... But I don't know how to do it without disrupting the spacing between the other links that are positioned at the right spot at the moment. Your suggestion, as well as others, moves everything from its current position.

Comment: @abudimir You can use nth-child(n) css. it is not affecting to others reference link : https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/n/nth-child/

Comment: It moves everything, mate... It does not affect spacing between other links but it moves them to the side... You can test it on the codepen example that I gave.

Comment: Thanks, Amarat. This is the closest to the solution but it's pretty complicated because all children from 1-5 have to get their margins set, left or right, and it's pretty tedious to set everything to its spot once you set one item where you want to, you have to set each one separately... and when setting each one the rest moves and then it's necessary again to adjust the first one. :D

Comment: No need to set margins for every li.  first set the default margin for all li like this #menu li { margin: 0 50px } and set different margin on desire li using nth-child css like this #menu li:nth-child(4) {  margin-right: 300px }

Comment: I don't get it how are we getting different results... So I made a screen recording on codepen example so that you can see what's happening on my end. Here's a link to my google drive.   https://drive.google.com/file/d/1U868qFhotiOzUNMGlwWGkW8bW8lTOekr/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @abudimir please accept the answer. if your problem is solved